# Mount volume from Host container to guest container(container inside container)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab

i need to run container inside container .The host container is running Pipeline and  dat from host container is mounted into guest container through docker compose.

volumes:
- ${PWD}:/workdir

earlier when pipeline was running on virtual machine it was  successful.Now when it is container inside container it is not happening. Any help  will be grateful.

Thanks

Comment: If one container launches another, there is no parent-child relationship; the second container is not "inside" the first in any way and the two containers have completely independent lifecycles.  A container can't mount another's filesystem and any bind mount is always interpreted as a location on the host system, regardless of where the container was launched from.